# Error returned from API. code: 403 - Firebase App Check Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-app-check

Our app has Firebase app check, but some users have this error, and the app crashes

Thanks

```
Caused by com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: Error returned from API. code: 403 body: App attestation failed.
       at com.google.firebase.appcheck.internal.NetworkClient.exchangeAttestationForAppCheckToken(NetworkClient.java:140)
       at com.google.firebase.appcheck.safetynet.internal.SafetyNetAppCheckProvider.lambda$exchangeSafetyNetJwsResultForToken$1$SafetyNetAppCheckProvider(SafetyNetAppCheckProvider.java:178)
       at com.google.firebase.appcheck.safetynet.internal.SafetyNetAppCheckProvider$$ExternalSyntheticLambda1.call(:4)
       at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzy.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@17.1.0:2)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
```

- 